# Bootstrap: nav-toggle won't move right & navbar-brand won't move left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The project is located at: https://github.com/shadtek/utahrenfaire

The live website is at: http://www.utahrenfaire.org/

I'm a novice developer and most, if not all, of the css code is from a theme I found online because I don't have the spare time to fully code out a website like this from scratch.

On an iPhone 5 and other widths the nav-toggle covers the last letter of the brand. Like this:

[image: The last letter is covered.]

I tried editing syles in lightblue.css but nothing I did worked. I tried moving the brand to the left and I tired moving the toggle to the right. It seems like my css styles are being ignored.

In lightblue.css this is where I thought I could just change the right: 0px to right: -21px but that didn't take.

[image: Changing this doesn't do anything.]

When I tried changes in the devtool for Chrome it seemed like I fixed it and it would just be a matter of targeting the correct element to override the scss file. But that did nothing as I already showed in the above image.

[image]

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong so I can fix this. I thought I did my due diligence in looking at this in all the different phone-browser widths in Chrome devtools but I guess I can't trust that tool anymore

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add padding-left:1.5em to: (Maybe first add an id to the `<a>` and then use that in your css)

```
<a href="#" class="js--nav-toggle -nav-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style="
    /* display: inline-block; */
    margin-left: 5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
"><i></i></a>
```

Comment: I added an id of nav-tog and then put  #nav-tog {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
} and this resulted in no change.

Comment: Thanks for the help BamBam

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was not looking at my localhost as I did changes I was looking at live.